# Select specific columns from table with JPA in java

Tags: jpa

I want to write a Query for getting specific columns.using

```
entitymanager.createQuery("SELECT u.name FROM Department u").getResultList();
```

however it  returns object is not an instance of declaring class.
What is the correct way to get specific column from table in jpa.as a provider i am using Hibernate

Comment: It returns `Object[]` as per what the JPA spec tells it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns list of objects (it would be hard for JPA to guess what types are you returning). But luckily you can give it a hint with [`TypedQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) like this

```
TypedQuery<String> query = em.createQuery("SELECT u.name FROM Department u",
    String.class);
List<String> departmentNames = query.getResultList();
```